# Are vectors equal when their product is equal?

Tags: linear-algebra

When we have such a simple outer product on two sides of the equation as below:

$aa^T$ = $bb^T$

where a and b are vectors, does it necessarily means a=b?

Comment: What have you tried? Any example?

Comment: I wanted to prove something

Comment: What if $a=-b$?

Comment: I reached this point, some constant around this equation.
now I want to write a based on b

Comment: It is good when you reach a point. After this is the right time to post a question (and not before). So you can get more help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No**.  Here is a counter example: $a = (1,-1)$ and $b = (-1,1)$.  Then $aa^T = bb^T$ but $a \ne b$.

Comment: As I understand it, the question is about the [outer product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_product) of two vectors (which produces a matrix), not about the inner product.

Comment: Oops, went a touch too far.  Edited.

Comment: but a is -b, it means a is in the span of b. or a = coef*b

Comment: @patric in this example that is correct, but that doesn't solve your problem, since $a \ne b$ is still true